# Matrix Representing

Tags: math, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-optimization

How can the matrix for R<sup>-1</sup>, the inverse of the relation R, be found from the matrix representing R, when R is a relation on a nite set A?

Comment: Isn't this more appropriate for http://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @Pablo Not necessarily. The basic business of matrix inversion is the stuff of any linear algebra textbook, but there are plenty of complications that arise from actual numerical implementation on a computer. I'd point the OP to [Numerical Recipes](http://www.nr.com/) in the first instance, but I'm rather out of touch.

Comment: What is a ``nite set''? Did you mean finite?

Comment: But those complications that make it not always trivial to accomplish do not make it belong here, but in a numerical analysis/numerical linear algebra class or textbook. A full depth discussion of the issues is far beyond what can be written here, while a cursory description will be of essentially little value.

Comment: A 'nite set' is what a 'finite set' looks like when you copy and paste it from the PDF file containing your homework questions without proofreading to check for missing ligatures.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the transpose of R. I guess by the inverse you mean that if S is the inverse of R, then aRb iff bSa. And I guess by the matrix you mean one with ones and zeros to indicate when aRb holds.